# Como habilitar cors en Firebase Hosting ? Angular10+

Tags: angular, firebase, api, backend

soy nuevo deployando a firebase, tengo un proyecto de prueba en angular10+ que consiste en consumir una api la cual en local funciona bien, pero ya que la deployé a Firebase hosting me da el error de Cors.

Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=api (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

no utilizo cloud functions ni nada de eso, simplemente deployé a firebase hosting. Y necesito aceptar esa cabecera en firebase para que tenga el funcionamiento necesario de manera global en la aplicación web.

Alguna ayuda que me puedan proporcionar? como dije soy nuevo en firebase y estoy aprendiendo algunas cosas pero esto no se enseña mucho.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Ya leíste la documentación de `Firebase` sobre los "encabezados"? [Configura encabezados](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config?hl=es#headers) Tal vez podría ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: Si, ya implementé lo que estaba ahí pero no responde, es por ello que pregunto... de pronto alguien puede saber.

Comment: En que esta escrito tu backend?

Comment: la api es pública, por lo tanto no soy el propietario de la api, por lo que no puedo determinar en que está escrita... en local angular no se queja de los cors pero al deployar si que se queja.